# Trying to use LoudML for Mainflux Application

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to integrate LoudML in my Mainflux application. There are lots of devices to be used and to monitor each signal's variation using the LoudML required to create a Model(https://loudml.io/guide/en/loudml/reference/master/_advanced_example_using_filters.html) for each signal, which can cause problem with the application performance because I have to create model for each signal dynamically when the device is created.

**I am using following approach to solve this problem. Please let me know if there are any other way to do so.**

I was thinking to categorize the signals in single modal which has same threshold values.